# Are there any tools for easily creating structure charts?

Tags: documentation-generation

I need to create a [structure chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_chart) as part of a school assignment, but all the normal chart and graph creation programs I have used such as [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) and [draw.io](https://draw.io/) lack the symbols needed.

Does anyone know of any similar programs that can be used to create a structure chart?

Comment: Note this question is probably better of on the sister site https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, @albert. I'll try asking on one of those.